# Como obtener el atributo data de un option seleccionado

Tags: javascript, html

Hola tengo un select que es el siguiente:

```
<form id="frmadd">
  <label >Seleccionar producto</label>
  <br>
  <select type="number" name="buscadorvivoop" id="buscadorvivoop" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:260px; " onchange="data(this);">
    <option value="0">ninguno</option>
    <?php 
      while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)):
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ver[0]; ?>" data-img="<?php echo $ver[2]; ?>">
      <?php echo $ver[1] ?> 
    </option>
    <?php 
      endwhile; 
    ?>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Cantidad a agregar</label>
  <input type="number" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" class="form-control input-sm"  style="width:260px;" value="0" size="15" onclick="if(this.value=='0') this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='0'" onfocusout="addtabletemp('frmadd')"/>
    <br>
</form>
```

para tratar de obtener el atributo y saber que option esta seleccionado hago uso del atributo `onchange()` para enviar a la función data() dicho elemento:

```
<script>
  function data(element){ 
    var url = element.getAttribute('data-img');
    if(url==null){
      document.getElementById("imgpro").style.display = 'none'; 
    }else{
      document.getElementById("imgpro").src=url;
      document.getElementById("imgpro").style.display = '';
    }
  }
</script>
```

pero no me obtiene el atributo . Espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar esto para llegar al **option** seleccionado:

```
onchange="data(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);"
```

o bien esto otro dentro del javascript:

```
var url = element[element.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-img');
```

donde lo que hacemos es usar la propiedad [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) para delimitar el **option** que se está seleccionando.

Comment: muchas gracias!!